# React - Firebase - RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a React application that uses an "onSubmit" button to trigger `handleSignUp()`. However, each time I call `handleSignUp()` it gives this error

> TypeError:
>   _base__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor

firebase initialize  -base.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID
});

export default app;
```

SignUp.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import app from "./base";

class SignUp extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new app.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(this.recaptcha, {
      size: "normal",
      callback: function(response) {
        console.log("reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.");
      },
      "expired-callback": function() {
        console.log("Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.");
      }
    });
    window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
      window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
    });
  }

  handleSignUp = async () => {
    var phoneNumber = "+16505554567";
    var appVerifier = new app.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container");

    try {
      await app
        .auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function(confirmationResult) {
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.recaptcha = ref)}>
        <h1>Sign up</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSignUp}>
          <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SignUp);
```

and also run  `var appVerifier = new app.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container");` automatically refresh the web page

Comment: can you post the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I spent 3hrs on this and finally found the issue.
When you initialize firebase app like

```
app.initializeApp(config);
```

then you can call methods using: **app.auth()**

```
app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

and to create RecaptchaVerifier instance, you must use: **app.auth**

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new app.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('captcha-container', {
        'size': 'invisible'
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also face this issue and resolved. This code absolutely help to signIn  using firebase phone auth

Firebase.js

```
import * as Firebase from 'firebase';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID
});
Firebase.initializeApp(app);
export default Firebase;
```

signup.js

```
    import React, { useState  } from 'react';
    import Firebase from './container/Firebase';
    import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
    import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'

    const Signup= () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

function setuprecaptcha (){
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new Firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
        size: 'invisible',
        callback: function (response) {
            console.log("recature resolved")
            this.onSignInSubmit();
        }
    });

}

 
function onSignInSubmit(event) {
    
    event.preventDefault();
    setuprecaptcha();
    var phoneNumber = value;
    var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    Firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function (confirmationResult) {
            console.log("Success");
            // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
            // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            var verificationId = window.prompt("Enter otp")
            confirmationResult
                .confirm(verificationId)
                .then(function (result) {
                    // User signed in successfully.
                    var user = result.user;
                    user.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
                        window.localStorage.setItem('idToken', idToken);

                       
                        console.log(idToken);
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
                    console.error("Error while checking the verification code", error);
                    window.alert(
                        "Error while checking the verification code:\n\n" +
                        error.code +
                        "\n\n" +
                        error.message
                    );
                });

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("sign Up error:" + error.code);
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecaptchaVerifier` constructor resides in `firebase.auth`. You need to pass `window.recaptchaVerifier` as the second argument to `signInWithPhoneNumber`.